# Can I restore an older save from the cloud?

Tags: borderlands-3

My computer crashed while playing the game. When I launched it, the launcher asked if I wanted to upload the local save to the cloud, or download an older version from the cloud. I chose the first option. Upon launching the game, it told me that the save data was corrupt and forced me to reset to defaults.

I lost a ton of progress with my characters.

Can I somehow download this older save from the cloud, or is my only option to start all over?

Comment: Since I haven't played Borderlands 3 yet, I can't give a definitive answer. But if the saves are stored to the Documents folder and you're backing it up to OneDrive, you may restore a previous version of the save from OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

afaik you probably dont have any other option than starting over, since you uploaded your local files to the cloud aswell, the previous save was overwritten and such you only have that corrupt save. 
i feel with you. I'm sorry